# Can Hugo in the alternate (no island) timeline see dead people?

Tags: lost

Can the version of Hugo in the alternate timeline (the one where he's CEO of the chicken place) see dead people?  I don't remember him ever seeing dead people, but I've been watching this spread over a long time period...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was no "alternate timeline." There's [only one history](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Time_travel#Temporal_paradoxes_and_the_rules_of_time_travel) in Lost, and it appears to be immutable.

> The "[sideways flashes](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Flash_sideways)" from season 6 were not an alternate timeline, they were an [afterlife](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Flash_sideways_world) constructed to help the Losties deal with their issues.
>
>  So that Hugo sees nothing *but* dead people. Same with everyone else there.

Comment: They weren't actually an afterlife, but really bad writing by talentless hacks that had no plans for where the show was going and no clever tricks to fool us into thinking that they had. It's bad when fan theories are far superior to the show itself.

Comment: Can you add a canonical source for this? I never realized <spoiler>the stuff in the spoiler text</spoiler>. Also, @JohnO "Christian Shepard" :P

Comment: @CamelBlues From my vague memory, it was revealed in the final episode.

Comment: Lostpedia is generally pretty reliable (as far as wikis go) and they discuss it [here](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Flash_sideways). As Keen recollects, it was the series finale, which was a 2 hour episode, that revealed the truth regarding the so-called "flash sideways".

Comment: [Page 121 of the script](http://spoilertv.co.uk/images/archived-old-shows/lost/season-6/Misc/The%20End%20-%20Script%20Pages/121.jpg.php) confirms this. Full script [here](http://darkufo.blogspot.com/2012/07/the-end-3-pages-from-script.html#.UT9sujcufhx)

Comment: @JohnO i must be an idiot because i think the show is brilliant.  yes the ending is a bit wonky in places but overall i think it is great.

Comment: @zipquincy Yes, no.